# How to emit event from child to parent in Vue3 with <script setup> syntax?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have the following component:

```
<SomeModal :is-modal-active="isAddingThing" @close="isAddingThing = false" />
```

Inside that component looks like this:

```
<script setup>
import { defineProps } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
    isModalActive: Boolean,
})

const handleClose = () => {
    emit('close') // doesn't work
}
</script>

<template>
<V-Modal @close="handleClose">
    ...
</V-Modal>
</template>
```

How do I emit to parent?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### Update 2022 - for `Vue 3.2` and newer

The `useContext` and `getCurrentInstance` APIs were deprecated and are no longer exposed to the Vue 3 API. Instead of that, you should use the `defineEmits` at the root level on the setup script.

```html
<template>
  <button @click="action('')"></button>
</template>
<script setup>
  const emit = defineEmits(['close', 'unClose'])
  const action = (id) => emit('close', val);
</script>
```

and for typescript the definition would be:

```js
const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: 'close', val: string): void
  (e: 'unClose', id: number): void
}>()
```

---

### Outdated, Pre-`Vue 3.2`

- You don't need to define emit at all to run `$emit` from the template
- `useContext` provides the emit function for use in setup function
- using `defineEmits` adds the list of emits to the component (equivalent to `emits:` definition of component) but doesn't help with the emit

`useContext` and `defineEmits` are deprecated as of Vue 3.2, use `getCurrentInstance` and `defineEmits`

---

#### `useContext`

```html
<template>
  <button @click="action('')"></button>
  <!-- emit is defined through useContext -->
  <button @click="emit('action1','')">1</button>
  <!-- $emit here doesn't need to be defined -->
  <button @click="$emit('action2','')">2</button>
</template>
<script setup>
  import { defineProps, useContext } from 'vue'
  const { emit } = useContext()
  const action = (id) => emit('action', id);
</script>
```

Note that vetur extension might tell you that it's deprecated and that you should use `useSlots` and `useAttrs` instead. If you want to use `emit` from the script, those, obviously, won't help with that.

#### `getCurrentInstance`

```js
import { defineProps, getCurrentInstance} from 'vue'
const { emit } = getCurrentInstance()
```

In addition to running an emit, vue3 allows (recommends‍♂️) that the emits are defined, so the component parent might know what events a component might emit. To do that using the `<script setup>` form, you can use `defineEmit`

```html
<script setup>
  import { defineEmit } from 'vue'
  const emit = defineEmit(['action'])
  const action = (id) => emit('action', id);
</script>
```

This will allow sending `action` emit event, but if you emit a `doit` although it will still emit, you'll get a warning in the console

> *[Vue warn]: Component emitted event "doit" but it is neither declared in the emits option nor as an "onDoit" prop.*

Comment: Thanks! I even just solved it too using the import `defineEmit` https://learnvue.co/2021/05/explaining-the-new-script-setup-type-in-vue-3-major-takeaways-from-the-rfc/

Comment: I like the `useContext` one a little more though it seems less rigid

Comment: updated answer with defineEmit example from learnvue

Comment: I like that's it's more explicit, however I **suspect** `defineEmit` also updates the `emits:` part of the component, so it might be a more appropriate solution (since `useContext` only makes the emit function available)

Comment: It might be helpful if you can update it again to show how to use both emit functions at the same time using `defineEmit`. It's not clear how to use `change` and `delete` when passing params.

Comment: For example, is it simply `emit('delete', props.id)` ?

Comment: did another update with more context and added example

Comment: `useContext` and `defineEmit` are deprecated now. Use `getCurrentInstance` and `defineEmits`

Comment: use context is not in the docs so thanks I have been searching for this for a while!

Answer (score 62):

With Vue version 3.2, if you want to emit an event from inside `<script setup>`, then all you have to do is define your emits with the `defineEmits()` method that is automatically available inside `<script setup>` (you don't have to import it), then you can emit the event by calling `emit('myEventName', myParams)`. Here's some sample code...

```html
<script setup>
const emit = defineEmits(['eventA', 'eventB'])
function btnClick(params) {
    emit('eventA')
    emit('eventB', params)
}
</script>
```

Comment: This does not work for me I get ReferenceError: emit is not defined